# Using environment variables defined in settings.json within the 'cwd' option of a task

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

My settings.json file contains a custom environment variable:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
        "BUILDDIR": "${workspaceFolder}/build"
      }
}
```

And my tasks.json file contains a basic command that should print the BUILDDIR as the cwd:

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "echo",
        "type": "shell",
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${env:BUILDDIR}"
        },
        "command": "echo $BUILDDIR is $PWD",
        "problemMatcher": []
    }
]}
```

But my output is:

```
/Users/me/scratch/build is /Users/me/scratch
```

It seems as though the environment variables in settings.json are not being loaded before the 'cwd' option is resolved. Is this by design, or is this a bug?

I'm trying to define a variable that I can modify without restarting VS Code to run a task on different directories. Yes I realize there are other ways to achieve this, but this simple example demonstrates a lack of expected functionality.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you solved this problem ? I want `cwd` option to create the folder when it is not exist, is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this behavior is the result of how VSCode handles variables in the launch and tasks files. From the VSCode documentation:

> Variable substitution in debug configurations or tasks is a two pass process:
>
> In the first pass, all variables are evaluated to string results. If a variable occurs more than once, it is only evaluated once.
>
> In the second pass, all variables are substituted with the results from the first pass.
> A consequence of this is that the evaluation of a variable (for example, a command-based variable implemented in an extension) has no access to other substituted variables in the debug configuration or task. It only sees the original variables. This means that variables cannot depend on each other (which ensures isolation and makes substitution robust against evaluation order).

So, I'm interpreting the above to indicate that the $PWD command is executed on the first pass before the $cwd resolves its target folder.

Answer (score -1):

This wasn't supported until very recently. You can [now](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2809) use environment variables in your `settings.json` file.

In your example above, assuming that `workspaceFolder` is an actual environment variable, you would do:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
        "BUILDDIR": "${env:workspaceFolder}/build"
      }
}
```